# javascript onclick not calling the function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am currently trying to learn JavaScript. I have little experience in Web. Pardon me for this question.

I am trying to use a onclick event to a function.Unfortunately, it does not load the function.

```
<img id="btnPartDispatch" title="sometitle" class="img-rounded" src="~/Content/Images/dashboard/PartDispatch.png" width="115" height="115" onclick="HelloWorld()" />
```

function is in a different file:

```
function HelloWorld(){
alert"('hello world')"
}
```

However, if I change the onclick event to alert("Hello World") it works fine. 
like this:

```
<img id="btnPartDispatch" title="sometitle" class="img-rounded" src="~/Content/Images/dashboard/PartDispatch.png" width="115" height="115" onclick="alert('Hello World!')" />
```

Can someone tell me what I do wrong? 
Thanks

Getting the javascript files on this way:

```
@section scripts
{
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var secondsToClosePopup = 1000 *  @Functions.GetNumberOfSecondsToClosePopup();
     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.multiple.select.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/service.js")"></script>
}
```

Project is ASP.net

Comment: The first version should produce a `SyntaxError`

Comment: We need to know how are you importing the file with the HelloWorld function.

Comment: You must have if as a function. `alert ()`. You also have alternative. Use get element by Id event listener.

Comment: SyntaxError . your function will be like this  `function HelloWorld(){
            alert('hello world');
        }`

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, it might be misleading. I've deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the double quotes from this:

```
alert"('hello world')"
```

in

```
alert('hello world')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert"('hello world')"` will throw syntax error, because it must be `alert('hello world');`

---

**Why *it must be*?**

[`alert` or `window.alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is a function that displays browser's default dialog box.

Since its a `function`, you will have to add `()`  after its name to call it, and pass necessary arguments(*message*) that it expects.

Hence `alert('hello world')`.

Also as a side note, since you are binding `onclick` in HTML, make sure that your function is loaded before DOM is loaded. Else it will throw error.

Comment: I'm just wondering should this be considered as a typographical mistake or not?

Comment: I think its a misunderstanding on how to use functions in general

Comment: @Justinas, I've updated your answer considering that OP is beginner. If its not required, please revert it or if any of the information is incorrect, please rectify it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

your syntax for calling alert method is wrong. You can use it like this

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="HelloWorld()">Click me</button>
<script>
function HelloWorld() {
    alert("Hello World");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see other answers as this rectification has been addressed in other answers and this will be repetition.  Would request you to either add something that others have not addressed or remove your answer